# Error running doctrine:fixtures:load in heroku

Tags: symfony, heroku, doctrine

I deploy a symfony application to heroku. When I try to run the command:

```
heroku run php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

I get the error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                           
  There are no commands defined in the "doctrine:fixtures" namespace.  

  Did you mean one of these?                                           
      doctrine:database                                                
      doctrine:generate                                                
      doctrine:query                                                   
      doctrine:schema                                                  
      doctrine:mapping                                                 
      doctrine:cache                                                   
      doctrine
```

Everything else seems to work in my local environment. If this is not the right way to load values into a mysql database in heroku using doctrine, what is it then?

My **Composer file** is:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "*",
        "sensiolabs/security-checker" : "2.0.1",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "~2.4",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/debug": "~2.6"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "liip/functional-test-bundle": "~1.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.6-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

My **config_prod.yml** file is:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters_prod.php }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    translator:      { fallback: en }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:          { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml" }
    form:            true
    csrf_protection: true
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:      { engines: ['twig'] } #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale: en
    session: ~
    fragments: { path: /_fragment }
    router:
        strict_requirements: "%kernel.debug%"

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    bundles: []
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    # java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool: { type: memory }

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: INCES\ComedorBundle\Entity\UserAdmin

    registration:
        form:
            type: inces_comedor_registration

knp_paginator:
    page_range: 5                      # default page range used in pagination control
    default_options:
        page_name: page                # page query parameter name
        sort_field_name: sort          # sort field query parameter name
        sort_direction_name: direction # sort direction query parameter name
        distinct: true                 # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
    template:
        pagination: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sliding.html.twig     # sliding pagination controls template
        sortable: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig # sort link template

knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
        options:    []

monolog:
  handlers:
    nested:
      type: stream
      path: "php://stderr"
```

**EDITED**

My **AppKernel** file:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
            new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
            //new Acme\HelloBundle\AcmeHelloBundle(),
            new INCES\ComedorBundle\INCESComedorBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\KnpSnappyBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            //$bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\LiipFunctionalTestBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved adding this to my **AppKernel**:

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('prod'))) {
    $bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle();
}
```

Thanks anyways.

Comment: You can simply add the middle line after `new Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\KnpSnappyBundle(),`, and the bundle will be available in all the environments.

Answer (score 12):

#### Symfony 4

For the next people running into this issue, if you are on Symfony 4, add this line in the `config/bundles.php` array:

```
Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle::class => ['all' => true]
```

Then clear your cache (as Rick Slinkman said in the comments)

Comment: Clearing the cache after doing this is also a smart move